# Ansible: Use Dynamic Inventory to get hostnames from a subnet

Tags: ansible, subnet

I need to run an ansible playbook on some hosts all on the same subnet.

However, I do not know what there hostnames are as they are always changing, however the subnet will remain the same.

Is there a way to use dynamic inventory to find all the hosts on a given subnet?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes it is possible. What platform are you using for your hosting? e.g. AWS, Vagrant etc.

Comment: I'm using Vagrant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Vagrant documentation. It already produces a dynamic inventory suitable for Ansible.

The documentation on Vagrant includes this page for [Ansible](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_intro.html):

> Vagrant will generate an inventory file encompassing all of the virtual machines it manages, and use it for provisioning machines.
>
> ...
>
> the generated inventory file is stored as part of your local Vagrant environment in `.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory`

Using Ansible with the `-i` option to specify the inventory should work. You can test it by listing the hosts:

```
ansible -i .vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory --list-hosts
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 4):

A trivial solution could be

```
nmap -n -sn 172.17.0.0/24 -oG - | awk '/Up$/{print $2}' > myInventory && ansible -i myInventory all -m ping
```

For more elegant solution look at [Dynamic Inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html) and [Developing Dynamic Inventory Sources](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html)

Comment: Thanks for this. I've used this to create my inventory file for testing with Vagrant to check the correct machines are being chosen.